# Cannot access "instance" or detail view of an object from react frontend with Django rest framework backend

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

So, I have this view for my models, on a `django-rest-framework` project

```
class GenreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

This is my serializer:

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('name', 'artist', 'albums')
        depth = 2
```

On urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'genre', views.GenreViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('rest-framework/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now, I have a react based frontend app, to access this object, if I access the recordset, meaning, the list of all the objects, then I'm perfectly able to do it, but, if for example, I want to access, just one of the objects in database, something like:

```
path/to/url:8000/object/id
```

Then I got this error, but only from the frontend, the react app:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-framework/genre/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the 
resource with CORS disabled.
```

Actually, I do have `django-cors-headers` installed, and also configured on my settings.py file. As I said, I can access the object list, listing all the objects into db, just not the detail.

On my settings.py I have:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ("x-requested-with", "content-type", "accept", "origin", "authorization", "x-csrftoken")

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
]
```

Obviously, this is insecure, I just using it for my local "experiment"

Also added it to `INSTALLED_APPS` ie (corsheaders), and on `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, like: `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',`

I even have this on settings: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

It is worth mentioning, that I don't have a particular APIview for that, although I can access it from the backend, meaning, using the drf built-in user interface.

This only happens from the react instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS instead of CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL

Comment: Thank You, same thing, I'm able to see that error on chrome's console

Answer (score 1):

You need add the values found in your class to the headers list.For example;

`CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ("x-requested-with", "content-type", "accept", "origin", "authorization", "x-csrftoken", "name", "artist", "albums")`